# How to get .libPaths() to use old R package installation after downgrading R?

Tags: r, ubuntu-22.04, rstudio-server

I'm using R-studio server as an admin on Ubuntu LTS 22.04 and can change anything necessary. An automatic update unfortunately "upgraded" my old R 4.2.2 installation to 4.3.1. This practically ruined the whole setup I had with a lot of old packages that are not compatible with the new version of R. I found a way to re-install the 4.2.2 version of R (in a separate location) and I updated my R-studio configuration file to use it. R-studio server now uses 4.2.2 again, but it no longer recognizes the installed 4.2 packages even though its the 1st folder listed in the .libPaths():

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/home/myusrname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2"
[2] "/opt/R/4.2.2/lib/R/library"
```

The second directory is right by the location of the 4.2.2 R install. 
Any ideas what could be causing this? I restarted the server, the computer, and the session and everything.

Comment: How exactly are you determining that the server is no longer recognizing the 4.2 packages? If it's listed first in the `.libPaths()` then that should be what it's using. Are you sure the packages are in that folder? Are they returned when you run `installed.packages()`?

Comment: For all previously installed packages that I try to load I get a variation of either "Error in "package": there is no "package" called "package"" or "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘package’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):"
I can guarantee that the packages are still there in that first .libPaths() folder.

Comment: So what does `installed.packages()` return? Can you confirm that you are trying to open a package that's listed there? What does `list.files(.libPaths()[1])` return?

Comment: those both return the list of packages installed in the first .libPaths() folder, including the ones i'm trying to use. However the .Library variable is curiously pointing to the second .libPaths() directory if that's helpful. I've tried changing .Library to the first directory but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: If you must, you can actually also move the packages out of a 'versioned' patch such as `/home/myusrname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2"` into an unversioned one such as `/opt/R/library` that persists across R upgrades (and/or a default like `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`).  I have used the default location for 20+ years without issues.

Comment: The `.Library` directory always points to the default library, which is the one where the base packages live.  `.libPaths()` can include others, generally before `.Library`, so there's nothing unusual with what you saw.  I would guess the reason you are having problems is that R 4.3.1 updated some of the packages.  Restore the directory from a backup, and you should be fine.  (If you don't have a backup, you should just wipe out the local lib and rebuild it from scratch.  And set up a proper backup scheme.)

Comment: RESOLVED: There were additional library dependencies referenced in other locations that were causing my packages of interest to fail. I have added them to .libPaths() and that seems to have fixed the issue:
`[3]"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"`                          
`[4] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"`                                
`[5] "/usr/lib/R/library"`    
My only remaining question is why are there so many different default package install locations?